# how to convert int array to nullable int array without looping over the elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable

how to convert `int array` to `nullable int array` without looping over the elements?

```
project.Suppliers = project.ProjectSuppliers.Select(proj => proj.ProjectSupplier).ToArray();
```

in the above code I am trying to assign `project.ProjectSuppliers.Select(proj => proj.ProjectSupplier).ToArray();` to the nullable array `project.Suppliers` but I can't because it is nullable so what is the best way to do this without looping over the elements one by one.

Comment: What is the purpose none of them will be null. Then again the model of suppliers seems inconsistent. It should be supplierid's? Why have null in there it's looking odd.

Comment: it is possible for the project to does not have any supplier.

Comment: In that case the array is null or empty but the elements still are int's

Comment: @Wouter: `project.Suppliers` may be used in other situations where the values could be null, so its declared type is `int?[]`. It's true that in this case the array will have no null values in it, but it still has to be of the correct type in order to assign it to the Suppliers property.

Comment: Any example; because this sounds like a fallacy (and following such reasoning object[] might also be plausible). An array of null suppliers (id's). What does it tell you when you have a few null suppliers on the project. To me it looks that in such a case you could separate the code into 2 different concerns. Of course the assignment is solved by casting but there might be a more structural solution to the underlying real problem by understanding why the type is int?[]. (Btw based on the reply int[] suffices, it looks like iterative development started with one or no supplier typed int?)

Comment: @Wouter: You're asking the right questions. Asking "why is this null" is a good first reaction to anything nullable, especially when you're talking about a collection of nullable things. In most cases (and probably this one) there are better patterns. This could be legit when an item's index in the array has implicit meaning. For example: imagine a Sudoku board represented by a collection of nullable integers (where null means nothing has been entered in a given square). A CompletedSudokuBoard might be a collection of non-nullable integers which you could map onto a SudokuBoard.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior In this case I guessed that there wasn't any value in the index and the int were just referring to primary keys. Besides that this question is about a project with `Suppliers` and `ProjectSuppliers`. then each `ProjectSupplier` (named `proj`) has another `ProjectSupplier`? This looks very smelly and highly questionable and if the index of the Suppliers was somehow related to the ordering of the ProjectSuppliers it would even be more smelly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two options:

Cast the items in your Select statement:

```
project.Suppliers = project.ProjectSuppliers
    .Select(proj => (int?)proj.ProjectSupplier)
    .ToArray();
```

Use `Cast<>()`:

```
project.Suppliers = project.ProjectSuppliers
    .Select(proj => proj.ProjectSupplier)
    .Cast<int?>()
    .ToArray();
```

The first option will probably have slightly better performance when using LINQ to Objects, and it'll probably have fewer surprises. (Some types use overloaded operators for explicit casts in code, but `Cast<>()` will throw an exception for the same conversion because its internal code doesn't know what those types are at compile time.)

The second option is more concise when you've got a precomposed `IEnumerable<>` or `IQueryable<>` and you don't want to create a whole `Select()` statement just for this purpose.

I should also note that when you're using LINQ to Objects, both of these will iterate over the given collection. You cannot convert an array of one type to an array of another type in C#, because at run-time each array instance is aware of what type of object it's holding and how much space each of those objects are going to need. These methods just give you a nice chainable syntax, rather than requiring a `for` loop.

Comment: any reason for it to be faster than a loop?

Comment: @mcmillab: Normally this will have very similar performance to using a loop. Its advantage is in readability, composability, and conciseness, not performance.